# URL rewriting for static resources

Tags: static-resources, urlrewriter

I know you can serve static [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) by uploading it as a static resource, but is it possible to create a [URL rewrite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite%5fengine) rule for a static resource?

Something like this

```
if (url.startsWith('/coach')){    
    return new PageReference('/resources/coach/index.html');
}
```

Navigating directly to `/resources/coach/index.html` works, but the rewrite rule doesn't?

Ideally I'd love to do something even more advanced like this, to be able to access any file in a zip'd static resource.

```
List<String> segments = url.split('/');

if (url.startsWith('/coach')){    
    return new PageReference('/resources/coach/'+ segments[1]);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer: a 'tricky' attack surface indicates this may not be the best kind of problem to solve with Salesforce ;) so double check your real business requirements and push back on those if necessary!

> First idea:

You might use the [`Site.UrlRewriter`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm) interface to do this on a Force.com Site, for eg:

```
public class UrlRewriter implements Site.UrlRewriter {

    public PageReference mapRequestUrl(PageReference incoming) {
        return new PageReference('/resource/1394899484000/SiteSamples/SiteStyles.css');
    }

    public PageReference[] generateUrlFor(PageReference[] yourSalesforceUrls) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

However the return signature of the implementor must be a `PageReference` resolving to a *real* page! I tried this for real and Salesforce serves a `404`, not the file inside a zipped static resource!

> Second idea:

You could create a *real* Visualforce Page as a kind of proxy that serves up the contents of the zip file using Apex, and point your URL Rewriter at that page:

Example: https://stackexchange-developer-edition.na14.force.com/coach/foo/bar

**UrlRewriter.cls**

```
public class UrlRewriter implements Site.UrlRewriter {

    public PageReference mapRequestUrl(PageReference incoming) {
        return new PageReference('/apex/ResourceReader');
    }

    public PageReference[] generateUrlFor(PageReference[] yourSalesforceUrls) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**ResourceReader.page**

```
<apex:page controller="ResourceReaderController" contentType="text/plain">
    <apex:outputText value="{!Content}" escape="false" />
</apex:page>
```

**ResourceReaderController.cls**

```
public class ResourceReaderController {

    public String getContent() {
        return new PageReference('/resource/1394899484000/SiteSamples/SiteStyles.css').getContent().toString();
    }

}
```

> Third idea:

Maybe try using [Site URL Redirects](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_redirects.htm&language=en_US) which can do a `301` or `302` redirect you. It won't be transparent to the visitors, but you can see an example of that here:

Example: https://stackexchange-developer-edition.na14.force.com/coach/herp/derp

However these guys exist as `0H0` prefix objects and must be administered through the user interface. I'm not sure you will ever be able to upload a zip file and automatically drill into it.

[image: redirect]